# Finding the nth entry in an nsindexset

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray, nsindexset

Say i have an `NSIndexSet` called `aSet` with numbers ranging from 26-89.

`[aSet firstIndex]` gives me 26

`[aSet lastIndex]` gives me 89

What method would give the 3rd index (29)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4547484/480850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `NSIndexSet` can be used to access like that. You'll need to iterate through it. For instance -

```
int indexIwantToFind = 2;
int valueAtThisIndex = [aSet firstIndex];
for(int i = 0; i < indexIwantToFind; i++){
    valueAtThisIndex = [aSet indexGreaterThanIndex:valueAtThisIndex];
}
NSLog(@"%d", valueAtThisIndex); //This will give you 39
```

Comment: what if the indexset contained the numbers 26, 30, 39, 69, then this method would give the second index (30) and not what it should be (39)