# Random index from NSIndexSet

Tags: objective-c, foundation, nsindexset

I need to pick a random index from those included in an `NSIndexSet`.

<strike>For reference, `NSSet` defines the `-anyObject` method ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSet/anyObject)) for picking arbitrary objects from a set. Is there a similar functionality in `NSIndexSet`?</strike> (It turns out -anyObject is not guaranteed to return a random object from a set.)

If not, how could it be implemented?

**Note**: I have found an implementation [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/74962773/), but it involves iteration over the index set's elements. Ideally I would like to avoid enumeration.

**Edit**: To my disappointment, the documentation of `NSSet` states that `-anyObject` is not guaranteed to return a random object from a set. Unfortunately, the same conclusion can be drawn from the [`NSIndexSet` documentation, regarding the implementation of `-getIndexes:maxCount:inIndexRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIndexSet/getIndexes:maxCount:inIndexRange:)

Comment: I don't see any other way of getting values out of the index set other than enumeration.

Comment: That's a pity. I was hoping that NSIndexSet, fulfilling a conceptually similar role to the other foundation set classes, would incorporate such a basic functionality.

Comment: Well actually there is `getIndexes:maxCount:inIndexRange:` but that might be expensive too, unless you were happy to cache it.

Comment: `NSSet` `-anyObject` itself is actually not guaranteed to be random.

Comment: @l'L'l just discovered this myself. Edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

First generate a random number between `0` and `[indexSet count]-1`.

Now get the index at the `randomNum`th index from the indexSet. There is no `indexAtIndex:` method as such, but this code will give you a similar result :

```
NSUInteger index = [indexSet firstIndex];

for (NSUInteger i = 0, target = randomNum; i < target; i++)
  index = [indexSet indexGreaterThanIndex:index];
```

Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4547484/3894781).

Answer (score 0):

## without enumeration

you can do something on a lower level with allocating/releasing some memory manually for the indices without any enumeration, that presents a *random* index as well:

```
NSIndexSet *_set = ... // your input index set

NSUInteger *_integerCArray = malloc(_set.count * sizeof(NSUInteger));
#if __LP64__
    NSRange _indicesRange = NSMakeRange(0, UINT64_MAX);
#else
    NSRange _indicesRange = NSMakeRange(0, UINT32_MAX);
#endif
[_set getIndexes:_integerCArray maxCount:_set.count inIndexRange:&_indicesRange];
NSInteger _randomIndex = _integerArray[arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)_set.count)]; // the random index
free(_integerCArray), _integerCArray = nil;
```

---

## with enumeration

I know you told you are not interested in enumerations, and to be fair it is a not really an efficient way, but it also is definitely gives you a *random* index as you need, and much better to read and memory management is much safer in this case:

```
NSIndexSet *_set = ... // your input index set

__block NSInteger _counter = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)_set.count); // assume there are fewer indices in the set than UINT32_MAX
NSInteger _randomIndex = [_set indexPassingTest:^BOOL(NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    return --_counter < 0;
}];
```

---

*NOTE: this idea also could be optimised for `O(n/2)`, using `NSEnumerationReverse` option if the random counter is bigger than `_set.count / 2` but I did not worry about working out that in this answer, if the set is basically huge, that might be a good idea, but with a few hundreds of indices, you won't be trouble using even this clumsy solution.*