# How to get indices of NSArray using something like indexOfObject?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can use [NSArray indexOfObject: NSString] to get an index of my search for 1 item.  But what can I use or do to get an array of returned indices from my search?

thanks

Comment: Do you want to search for one element that may be repeated in the array, or search for multiple elements at once?

Comment: I have an NSArray of 1000 NSStrings that I am searching one particular NSString that may return multiple indices for their locations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905828/get-nsindexset-from-nsarray

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get multiple indices, you can use [`indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest%3a):

```
// a single element to search for
id target;
// multiple elements to search for
NSArray *targets;
...
// every index of the repeating element 'target'
NSIndexSet *targetIndices = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^ BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [obj isEqual:target];
    }];

// every index of every element of 'targets'
NSIndexSet *targetsIndices = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^ BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [targets containsObject:obj];
    }];
```

Support for blocks were added in iOS 4. If you need to support earlier versions of iOS, `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` isn't an option. Instead, you can use [`indexOfObject:inRange:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject%3ainRange%3a) to roll your own method:

```
@interface NSArray (indexesOfObject)
-(NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObject:(id)target;
@end

@implementation NSArray (indexesOfObject)
-(NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObject:(id)target {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [self count]);
    NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    NSUInteger idx;
    while (range.length && NSNotFound != (idx = [self indexOfObject:target inRange:range])) {
        [indexes addIndex: idx];
        range.length -= idx + 1 - range.location;
        range.location = idx + 1;
    }
    return [indexes autorelease];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to `indexOfObjectsPassingTest`, as @outis recommends, you could use `indexOfObject:inRange:` and loop over the results, updating the range to start after the last result finished, and updating the results into your own NSIndexSet, or NSMutableArray, etc.